# Location of the android sdk has not been setup in the preferences in windows OS

Tags: android

On Eclipse i go to  windows> Android SDK and AVD Manager and this message pops up: Location of the android sdk has not been setup in the preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to preferences, find "Android" on the sidebar and then there will be a box for SDK location, point it to the SDK. Read over http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html if you're still stuck.

Comment: I don't want to download and unzip the SDK. I want the SDK Manager to download it for me. But I can't run the manager without a folder already configured, AND tools in it. Java...

Comment: insure not - in your path,my sdk path:c:/android-sdk,change to android_sdk,it's work.Hope it's help.

Answer (score 0):

Here they have SpringSourceToolSuite which is a snapshot in time. It had the "\" bug too. (Using Windows so had to add a "\" instead of "/".) Irritating is right! So, the answer is that in Windows with SprinSource Tool Suite Version 2.8.1.RELEASE, Build Id: 201111221000, one needs to add a backslash. Actually, I did it manually in the Window=>Preferences:Android::SDK Location textedit and then hit Apply. "C:\Program Files\Opensource\android-sdk-windows\"
Thanks to Ganesh Krishnan, who answered this similar or same question WRT iOS in another question.